# Boiling and melting points of hydrocarbons

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, boiling-point, melting-point, physical-organic-chemistry

What happens while boiling and melting hydrocarbons? Which bonds are broken?

When we compare the boiling point (b.p.) and melting point (m.p.) of certain hydrocarbons the order is inverted. For example: *cis*-2-butene has b.p. higher than *trans*-2-butene, but the opposite is true for the m.p.

I am not able to understand why there is a different order. If there is only role of intermolecular forces, then why does the order come out to be different? What are the factors that affect boiling and melting point of hydrocarbons?

Comment: The intermolecular forces obviously depend on the *packing* in condensed matter. Also note the plural: force_s_. Actually a complex multidimensional force field. Why would they all have the same temperature dependence?

Comment: Btw. it _a_ _higher_ boiling/melting point. And pls. leave out the ALL CAPS, looks like you're shouting. That's not necessary here.

Comment: The entropy change of the two processes can dictate this reversal. Let me see if it can be the case here as well as to find a old answer of mine that address the point. Otherwise I'll write another one in due time.

Comment: The comment above is nonsensical in 2-butenes.

Comment: I don't understand why this is close. Not really because I have already answered to it, but I think OP couldn't have done much more than noticing the behaviour and correctly argue using reasonable sense that one might expect that stronger intermolecular forces reflects qualitatively in both solid and melt phase. It is in many cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer involves considering the two main factor that dictates packing or anyway molecular interactions (don't call them bonds!) in alkenes in the two different states.

These are the type of molecular interaction as well as the geometrical shape.

As for the shape, cis-alkenes have a kind of U bent geometry. This interfere with packing as compared to the cis case. Although they have a small electrical dipole moment, the hindered packing overrules dipole-dipole interactions in the solid state. As such, cis-alkenes melt at a slightly lower temperature as compared to the trans isomers.

Opposite, the geometrical requirements for packing are much less important in the liquid phase. Therefore the little polarity of trans-alkenes and the consequent dipole-dipole interaction fully add to the always present VdW forces.
As such, the boiling point of cis-alkenes is slightly higher than that of the trans isomers.