# Intermolecular Forces and State Change

Tags: intermolecular-forces

I know that intermolecular forces determine the state of a substance at a given temperature and that changing state involves the ability of a substance to overcome those forces.  I encountered a question that asks if intermolecular forces change during a state change.  My inclination is that the forces themselves don't change as they are a property of that particular substance, that it is the ability of the particles to overcome forces that drives the state change.  Am I correct, or are intermolecular forces themselves temperature-dependent?

Comment: Force does not know temperature when 2 molecules interact. The particular energy state of these molecules can belong to wide range of temperatures.

Comment: Look at my answer to this closed as not suitable question. I think this is an example about the subject of your question. The forces that dictate a phase are different, or they overall effect is different. Note that although a molecule is a well defined object, this is not true for the conformation it can assume. So even the reason for the forces might be or not there depending on T (P). https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/159591/boiling-and-melting-points-of-hydrocarbons. Similar thing can happen when geometrical changes are intrinsic to a phase formation.

Comment: So...let me see if I understand your last response---because a molecule's conformation can affect intermolecular attractions, and because its conformations are temperature (or pressure)-dependent, intermolecular forces can, indeed, change during a state change?

Comment: @KaraRowbotham for instance, the dipole electrical moment depends on shape, and the shape of an isolated molecule can be different than that in solid state. Another reason is that the range of various forces isn't the same, as such the predominant one depends on molecular interdistance. The same can be said for pi pi stacking, and so on. The "force themselves don't change" they role yes. As classical gravity is always expressed by the formula you know, but it can even become neglibile if m is too small or r is too big. Back to our chemical case, yes you can also say that there is always a mix.